# Should img[align=right] work?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have thousands of articles with inline images like this:

```
<img src='...' align='left'/>
```

and

```
<img src='...' align='right'/>
```

I would like to add padding using CSS as follows, but it doesn't work:

```
img[align=left] {padding-right:10px}
img[align=right] {padding-left:10px}
```

This seems not supported?

Comment: `img[align="left"]` - try it with the quotes

Comment: What browsers did you use for testing?

Comment: According to http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html, it should work in all 'modern' browsers except for IE6 and below. Have you tried inspecting things with firebug? Perhaps another rule is overriding this one.

Comment: Tried it Marc, but did not work :(

Comment: Oh, you're missing the terminating ; after your rules -- that may cause issues in some browsers.

Comment: @Marc B As long as the attribute value has the [identifier syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) the quotes are not needed.

Comment: @JasonLeBrun [citation needed] That is simply not true for the last value, as far as I know.

Comment: @bart You're probably not observing the effect, or doing some other thing wrong. It should work. Take a look at Phrogz's answer and see if that example works for you.

Comment: @Alin: I tend to lean towards being pedantic when writing out html, so I always put in quotes, even if not necessary.

Comment: @bart: Anything in Firefox's error console (shift-ctrl-j). If there's any css syntax errors, they'll get logged there.

Comment: Changed my CSS and now it does work. Apparently img {} overrules img[align=left] and img[align=right].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me (with or without quoting the value) on Win7/Chrome/8 and Win7/FF/3.6: http://jsfiddle.net/gLe3U/

You'll need to provide more details on the OS/browser/version giving you trouble, and perhaps provide a full test case (e.g. through http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: +1, and Ditto. bart, I tried your excerpts on a test page, and they worked. Perhaps you haven't defined the styles in the right place.

Comment: Changed my CSS and now it does work. Apparently img {} overrules img[align=left] and img[align=right].

Comment: img[align] should override img as it has a higher specificity unless you have an ID or class selector along with the img selector.