# Connecting Hardcoded align right HTML with CSS

Tags: html, css, hardcoded

I have pictures inside articles hardcoded like this:

```
<img border="0" align="right" src="http://www.domain/picture.jpg" width="300" height="450">
```

I cannot change this line of code but would like to add CSS for this image (which is aligned right only), is there any way this could be done without changing other alignments? (if I would add CSS to img then it would also change for pictures which are aligned center etc.)

I hope someone has time to answer :)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you also add the HTML and improve your explanation of what you want exactly?

Comment: So you want a rule that only affects image tags with `align="right"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should img\[align=right\] work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832207/should-imgalign-right-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use attribute selector

```
img[align="right"] {
  // your css
}
```

> The CSS attribute selector matches elements based on the presence or
>   value of a given attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Add style like this

```
img[align='right'] {
// Some styles
}
```

You can also add class to this image and then apply styles to that class.